# Ambiguous plpgsql query error with insert with select

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

So I got this error, I put the alias at `num_documento` (codigo "a.num_documento") but Postgres says `num_documento` doesn't exist.

```
ERROR: la referencia a la columna �num_documento� es ambigua 
Where: PL/pgSQL function "insertar_carga_giros"           
line 145 at sentencia SQ???
```

--Query function insertar_carga_giros

```
insert into bdsinc."codigo"(num_documento,id_tip_dcto,id_deudor) 
select distincta.num_documento,b.id_tip_dcto,b.id_deudor 
from bdsinc."carga" a
left join bdsinc."tb_deudor" b 
on a.num_documento=b.num_dcto 
and a.id_tip_dcto=b.id_tip_dcto
where b.id_deudor is not null and validacion=1;
```

How can I do an insert with select join inside in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You are only showing plain SQL. Where is the complete plpgsql function? The error is most likely in connection with the header of the function. Your version of PostgreSQL is missing, too.

Comment: Is that really "select distincta.num_documento" in your statement or is that a typo/copy-and-paste-o?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `INSERT` statement looks ok. You probably defined a variable name `num_documento` in your function that conflicts with the column name. Maybe an `IN` parameter?
Try renaming that variable.

Assuming that you actually have:

```
select distinct a.num_documento,b.id_tip_dcto,b.id_deud;
```

Comment: Well its was a bad copy-pasta i've solved the problem already, thanks!